# Powerpoint to saving a picture in .svg format

Tags: svg, microsoft-powerpoint, render-settings

I am drawing circuits in powerpoint for a report. The idea is to save this circuit as an .svg file which will be included in latex after converting it to.eps format. While saving the picture powerpoint does something wierd. The circuit diagram in powerpoint zoomed to 200% looks as follows:
[image]
And after saving it as svg looks as follows:
[image]
Why does powerpoint render it incorrectly? I opened the svg file in multiple tools, and all of them show the same results. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Is it really necessary to convert to SVG, then EPS?  I would skip both. Export as PDF from powerpoint, and use that in your LaTeX project. See this related post on Stack Overflow: [Inserting a PDF in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex)

Comment: The problem with exporting as a pdf are the white spaces. Power point does not give an option to remove the whitespaces. It exports the whole slide. With selecting the figure and using "save as" option i can get rid of the whitespaces. Although you are right that the anomaly i see while saving the images is not seen when i export it. Do you know how to get rid of the white spaces?

Comment: Can't you just make the slide size smaller, i.e. same size as your graphic? Sorry I'm not a powerpoint user so I can't tell you exactly how to do that. Maybe search for "custom slide size".

Comment: That is too much effort for a silly thing, time and again Microsoft products have failed me, i think this time though microsoft hit the nail in the coffin, i will be searching for alternatives from now on. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Have Microsoft products failed you, like really? It kinda sounds like you nailed the coffin shut yourself. Where in the product description of PowerPoint does it say it's for drawing circuit diagrams? I do 100% agree that it shouldn't have so many issues with SVG export, but it's clearly not the right tool for the job in the first place. There seem to be loads of apps specifically built for that purpose and even some web apps like this one https://www.circuit-diagram.org - I don't know if they are any good, but I would assume any of them would be a better experience than using PowerPoint...

Comment: And just to clarify, I get that this issue is not really related to drawing the diagrams, which seems to have worked out. It's a general issue affecting anyone exporting to SVG... or potentially anyways, but my point is that PowerPoint is a presentation app and SVG export is not one of its key features and probably something the average user would never need. PowerPoint has existed for like... 30 years and svg support was added like what? A few years ago maybe? I don't really know, but the point stands. It's far from the key features so I wouldn't be so mad at them for it not working.

Comment: I applaud your efforts in defending Microsoft, specially powerpoint, just like internet explorer asking whether I want it to be the default browser to replace chrome, the thing is i am paying for microsoft products, and specially in powerpoint one might want to draw straight lines and expect the output to be the same, and since powerpoint does give the option to save as .svg, all i want is for the straight lines to be in their position, i am not an artist and this is not a Picasso painting, straight lines to remain in position for an app i am shelling out money for is all i expect,

Comment: btw the app that you mentioned provides exactly the same thing as powerpoint, offcourse tailor made for circuit design which means a node in a circuit is  represented by a dot, which powerpoint cannot do, but i am not complaining about that, i am manually placing all the dots. again the free app gives an option to save as .svg, and i am pretty certain whithout even trying that the positions of straigt lines will be preserved

Comment: ohh and speaking of presentation app, there have been numerous times that powerpoint has rendered the figure wrong in presentation mode

Comment: If you are paying MS for a Presentation app... to make circuit diagrams and you're having trouble doing that, it's all on you as far as I'm concerned. Like I said they should fix the svg export issues, but you're laying it a little thick there... It's like going to a pizza place demanding they serve you a steak, like come on dude.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129774/discussion-between-ran-and-joonas).

Answer (score 1):

Powerpoint tends to do random things... It would be better to use an app that is more suited for this purpose like Inkscape.

In this case you then can open the svg file you already got and fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I already considered inkscape, but to me it is not very intuitive, do you know any other app/software specifically suited for drawing schematics? (apart from all the schematic editors combined with simulators)

Comment: I suggested Inkscape as it appears to be the most widespread free vector software.  Personally I would use Illustrator (expensive and probably not the most beginner friendly). But I'm sure this is a common problem and many people created apps for circuit drawings. 

Searching for "Electric Circuits Online Tool" I found this one that seems to be speciallized for the kind of thing you need and also supports svg export.
https://www.circuit-diagram.org/

Or people from https://electronics.stackexchange.com may know better which tool is best for this kind of things.

Comment: Lots of posts related to this on there. Here's just one of them I found, that may be an interesting read for you:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics

Comment: Thank you, that was quite a read, I am narrowing down to inkscape and a library https://github.com/fsmMLK/inkscapeCircuitSymbols, hopefully it works, since I have to redo around 40 figures, i will let you know the results.

Comment: update: the circuit symbols library does not work, apparently everything is written in python, with lots of dependencies, i will have to raise issues on github and stuff, again too much effort to simply draw basic circuit diagrams.